# Hibernate error: SQLGrammarException: la columna X debe aparecer en la cláusula GROUP BY o ser usada en una función de agregación

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Buenos días,

tengo la siguiente sentencia HQL con Hibernate 5.2.10 utilizando PostgreSQL como base de datos en una aplicación JAVA:

```
Query<Object[]> query = session.createQuery("SELECT fp.nombre, SUM(vfp.importe), fp.clase, fp.tipoFijo, COUNT(v.idVenta), fp "
            + "FROM FormaPago fp "
            + "JOIN fp.ventaFormaPagos vfp " 
            + "JOIN vfp.venta v "
            + "JOIN v.informe i "
            + "WHERE i = :informe AND (:tpv IS NULL OR v.tpv = :tpv) "
            + "AND ((NOT fp.tipoFijo ='F' AND NOT fp.tipoFijo ='A') OR fp.tipoFijo IS NULL) "           
            + "GROUP BY fp.nombre, fp.clase, fp.tipoFijo, fp "
            + "ORDER BY sum(vfp.importe)");
```

A la hora de resolverla, me aparece el siguiente error:

```
09:51:10.872ERROR {JavaFX Application Thread [VentaFormaPagoDAL:416 (obtenerDatosLiquidacionVentaFormaPagoByInforme)]} javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1423)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146)
    at org.cuatrogl.tpv.dal.VentaFormaPagoDAL.obtenerDatosLiquidacionVentaFormaPagoByInforme(VentaFormaPagoDAL.java:369)
    at org.cuatrogl.tpv.bll.VentaFormaPagoBLL.obtenerDatosLiquidacionVentaFormaPagoByInforme(VentaFormaPagoBLL.java:78)
    at org.cuatrogl.tpv.view.custom.CierreTurnoCaja.calcularDatosCierreInforme(CierreTurnoCaja.java:98)
    at org.cuatrogl.tpv.view.custom.handlers.HandleTurno.solicitarCierreInformeYPedirContadores(HandleTurno.java:801)
    at org.cuatrogl.tpv.view.custom.handlers.HandleTurno.cerrarTurno(HandleTurno.java:483)
    at org.cuatrogl.tpv.view.custom.handlers.HandleTurno.handleCerrarTurnoButton(HandleTurno.java:217)
    at org.cuatrogl.tpv.view.custom.handlers.HandleTurno$6.handle(HandleTurno.java:176)
    at org.cuatrogl.tpv.view.custom.handlers.HandleTurno$6.handle(HandleTurno.java:1)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2123)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1911)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:932)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2615)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2598)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2430)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2425)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1488)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: la columna «formapago0_.abrir_cajon» debe aparecer en la cláusula GROUP BY o ser usada en una función de agregación
  Position: 167
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2476)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2189)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:300)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:169)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:71)
    ... 87 more
```

El objeto "fp" es el que contiene la columna "abrir_cajón" y está listado tanto en la sentencia SELECT como en el GROUP BY. Cuando con Hibernate arrojo el SQL subyacente generado por el HQL observo que en el GROUP BY no se está listando las columnas del objeto "fp", mientras que en la SELECT sí.

Además, está misma sentencia funciona correctamente en otros compañeros que utilizan el mismo modelo de base de datos y misma versión de la aplicación pero con diferentes datos.

Gracias.

Comment: El punto sobre que la sentencia funciona correctamtente con otros compañeros es algo extraño. ¿Habéis comprobado si teneis la misma versión de "sql_dialect" (en la configuración de la conexión a BD de Hibernate)?

Comment: Gracias por contestar @SJuan76:
si, hemos comprobado dicha sentencia y es idéntica. De hecho, todo el archivo de configuración de Hibernate es el idéntico para todos ya que en desarrollo estamos atacando a nuestras bases de datos locales. Hemos vuelto a realizar una restaruación de la base de datos en cuestión en mi equipo y parece funcionar, pero no deja de ser algo muy extraño que en una base de datos no funcione esa sentencia y en otra sí, cuando el problema arrojado es de sintaxis y no es relativo al contenido.

Comment: En la sentencia del select tienes o un campo o un error al final: `, fp "`, que es? un campo válido o el alias de la tabla?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho es el alias de la tabla, está listado tanto en la SELECT como en el GROUP BY. La sintaxis es correcta.

Comment: No tengo mucha experiencia e postgresql pero al menos en tsql esa sintaxis es incorrecta. En el select solo van nombres de campo, a lo sumo un `fp.*`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho en lenguaje del código mostrado es HQL, un lenguaje utilizado para trabajar con el ORM Hibernate, el cual se encarga de traducirlo al SQL utilizado por el motor de base de datos subyacente.